# 'wc -m' shows one character too many

Tags: wc

I am writing a program on using `wc -m`/`wc -c` to count the amount of letters in a string. It counts the letters, but adds one extra. This is what I currently have:

```
echo "enter a word"
read var1
echo $var1 | wc -c
```

When I enter the word, it successfully does something, however, for example if I enter "test" it will output 5.

Why is it doing this and is there a fix?

Comment: Related: [How does word count work for newline (-l)? Number of newlines or lines](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116835/how-does-word-count-work-for-newline-l-number-of-newlines-or-lines/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the command you're using to pipe the string to `wc`. The `echo` command is slipping in an extra character at the end of your string, `test`, a new newline character, `\n`.

So in effect you're counting this: `test\n`. You can disable this behavior with the `-n` switch to `echo`.

```
$ echo -n "test" | wc -c
4
```

Or use a different command to generate your string, such as `printf`:

```
$ printf "%s" "test" | wc -c
4
```

#### Seeing what's happening

You can use `od` to see the actual characters that are getitng passed to the pipe like so:

```
$ echo "test" | od -c
0000000   t   e   s   t  \n
0000005

$ echo -n "test" | od -c
0000000   t   e   s   t
0000004
```